# Is there a way to see all Work Items type on Boards?

Tags: azure, devops, project-management, kanban

I've some custom Work Item types configurated for my Organization's projects. I'd like to see them all into the Boards sections:

[image]

But it just show "Issues" or "Epics" (not my custom ones), neither "All".

Can I see all Work Items on the Kanban columns?